# LINQ Query with NULLs

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have this LINQ query (sorry it;s a long one) that query sets from CRM 2011. Right now it pulls down data, but it doesn't include the ones with NULLs I want it to pull down the ones with and without NULLs. Anyway to do this with this query. I'm kinda stuck. Thanks!

Update: I've updated the code to include the two left joins to include NULLs. But now I am getting this error:

"The 'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' operation where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method."

Any ideas on how to fix the error?

```
var linqQuery = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
    join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"] into opp
    join n in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation") on r["opportunityid"] equals ((EntityReference)n["objectid"]).Id into notes
    from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from nt in notes.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(lProfileProperty.PropertyValue) && ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")

select new
  {
              OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
              CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
              Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
              ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
              Source = !r.Contains("new_sourcepick") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["new_sourcepick"],
              CreatedOn = !r.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)r["createdon"]).ToShortDateString(),
              CreatedOnSort = !r.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)r["createdon"]).Ticks.ToString(),
              State = !o.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : ((String)o["address1_stateorprovince"]),
              Zip = !o.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : ((String)o["address1_postalcode"]),
              Eval = !r.Contains("new_distributorevaluation") || ((OptionSetValue)r["new_distributorevaluation"]).Value.ToString() == "100000000" ? "NA" : r.FormattedValues["new_distributorevaluation"].Substring(0, 2),
              EvalVal = !r.Contains("new_distributorevaluation") ? "100000000" : ((OptionSetValue)r["new_distributorevaluation"]).Value.ToString(),
              DistributorName = !r.Contains("new_channelpartner") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Name,
              ContactStreetAddress = !o.Contains("address1_line1") ? string.Empty : o["address1_line1"],
              ContactStreetAddress2 = !o.Contains("address1_line2") ? string.Empty : o["address1_line2"],
              ContactCity = !o.Contains("address1_city") ? string.Empty : o["address1_city"],
              ContactState = !o.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : o["address1_stateorprovince"],
              ContactZip = !o.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : o["address1_postalcode"],
              ContactCountry = !o.Contains("address1_country") ? string.Empty : o["address1_country"],
              ContactPhone = !o.Contains("telephone1") ? string.Empty : o["telephone1"],
              ContactMobilePhone = !o.Contains("mobilephone") ? string.Empty : o["mobilephone"],
              ContactEmail = !o.Contains("emailaddress1") ? string.Empty : o["emailaddress1"],
              Notes = !r.Contains("new_distributornotes") ? string.Empty : r["new_distributornotes"],
              EstimatedCloseDate = !r.Contains("estimatedclosedate") ? string.Empty : r["estimatedclosedate"],
              MaturityValue = !r.Contains("estimatedvalue") ? string.Empty : ((Money)r["estimatedvalue"]).Value.ToString(),
              DistributorStatus = !r.Contains("new_distributorstatuspicklist") ? "Unopened" : r.FormattedValues["new_distributorstatuspicklist"],
              ColderNotes = !nt.Contains("notetext") ? string.Empty : nt["notetext"],
              ColderNotesCreatedOn = !nt.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)nt["createdon"]).ToShortDateString(),
              ColderNotesCreatedBy = !nt.Contains("createdby") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)nt["createdby"]).Name,
});
```

Comment: Are the nulls only in some of the tables or any of them?  It matters in what type of joins you need to do.  Linq can support left joins although it's a bit wonky.

Comment: NULLS can be in both of the tables annotation and contacts. Thanks!

Comment: You want to include NULL values gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") and gServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation")? If so you can try to do it by, changing type of JOIN used in the query.

Comment: ok, both of your joins need to be Left Joins.  I can post an example shortly.

Comment: You've updated the code. Please update the question to match (according to your comment below you're now getting an error). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change both of your joins to LEFT Joins.  You can follow the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

There are other syntaxes, but this should work for you.

Edit: Here is the syntax I use for this (sterilized so I hope I didn't break anything important).  It's a bit different but I find it easier to work with.  Hopefully this will help:

```
        var x =
            (from A in db.Table1
             from B in db.Table2
            .Where(p => p.Table1_ID == A.ID)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            from C in db.Table3
            .Where(c => c.Table2_ID == B.ID)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            where A.field1 == value1
            select new { [fieldlist] });
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my query above based on the example. I am getting this error now. "The 'GroupJoin' operation must be followed by a 'SelectMany' operation where the collection selector is invoking the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method." I there anyway to fix that?

Comment: I'm rushing out now, but I'm pretty sure one problem is the first .DefaultIfEmpty() comes before the second join.  There may be an additional problem I can look at when I get back.

Comment: I am updating my response with an example of the syntax I use.

Comment: This doesn't work. I found I had to use nested .AsEnumerable sub queries.

Comment: @Sentinel I realize this comes late after this question was asked, but could you by chance provide an example of how you solved the problem with those nested sub-queries?

Comment: Hi it's been ages and I no longer work with CRM linq to entities, but if I remember rightly what I had to do was .ToList() or AsEnumerable() (which compiles and executes the query) multiple times in the main query, joining on the results. Exact syntax I don't have handy.